# Localized .xib file not working through TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, testflight

I have an .xib file that I have localized to `Base` and `Arabic`. Both of these are Localized using the `Interface Builder`. In other words, the `Arabic` localization is not just a strings file.

This seems to work perfectly fine when I launch directly from Xcode to a device or simulator, but when I upload to TestFlight and download on a device in Arabic, the app only loads the Base .xib file...

Is this just a weird bug, or why won't the correct .xib file be loaded?

Comment: @Kamran it's a localized file. I don't decide it, the OS decides based on the Locale of the phone... That's what localization means...